# Long auth token or database fetch Rest API

Tags: mysql, rest

Is it better to store the full data of the logged user/client in the token or just the id and fetch its data from the database upon a request? The full data may be around 1500 chars

Comment: There's no accurate answer to this. Both approaches contain good and bad things. The only person who can tell you which one is correct is the person working on the project as a developer - which is you.

Comment: you are helpful thank you.